# Convert xls-fo to Docx

Tags: converters, docx, xsl-fo

I'm looking for a framework, code or somethingelse, to convert a xsl-fo file to docx. 
Currently i'm working on an converter, but i can't belive that's no code for these problem will be exists. 
My search results shows only code for the generation of pdf or rtf from xsl-fo.
Docx4j seems, that these framework can do this convert.
Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: XSL-FO is a format specifically designed for the production of PDFs. When you convert an XML file to an FO file, you throw away lots of information that would be useful for Word, e.g. named paragraph styles. It may be easier to convert the source XML to docx instead.

Comment: In the past, the xsl-fo file was convertet to a rtf document.

Comment: sure, I'm just saying there are easier ways to get what you want. Why was this route chosen?

Comment: The XSL-FO file underlying xml is unfortunately not to be used because it contains only results that are generated by a software. The XSL-FO is created by xpath and many other xsl files. I am not aware of the fact that a framework could create a DOCX file instead of an XSL-FO file.

Comment: @Hobbes I'm working in a project with the goal, to create a docx file instead a rtf. And these project have many ugly old code inside :-) Normal live in a old project.